# PHP/Codeigniter elseif not processing

Tags: php, codeigniter

I can't seem to get the elseif to process in the below php code. My database setup is noted below:

[image]

```
<?php // the following php is the bootstrapper for the friendship connector
    $selectedId = $_REQUEST['id'];
    $myuserid = $this->session->userdata('userid');

    $friendshipQuery = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM friends");
    $row = $friendshipQuery->row();
    foreach ($friendshipQuery->result() as $row) {
        if ($myuserid == $selectedId) { ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#addFriend").hide();
                });
            </script>
<?php } elseif ($row->relationType == 'requested') { ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    alert("hello");
                    $("#addFriend").replaceWith(<input type="submit" value="Accept Friend" style="width: 95px; height: 28px" class="button1" />);
                });
            </script>
<?php } } ?>
```

Comment: FYI The `$row = $friendshipQuery->row();` isn't needed.

Comment: The `elseif` will only run if `$selectedId` and `$myuserid` aren't equal.

Comment: I changed it to an if statement but still no luck.

Comment: Try to `var_dump($row->relationType)`, make sure it's what you want.

Comment: what happens if you remove the `if/elseif` so it's always gets executed?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/927xMWzG - nothing happens. I rewrote it a little bit. So I'm guessing it might have to do with my js. and this is the string i am getting back from the var_dump: string(9) "requested"

Comment: oh shoot lol i think i figured it out. i didn't place single quotes around my replaceWith

Comment: Yeah it works now. lol i feel so dumb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is right here:

```
$friendshipQuery = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM friends");
    $row = $friendshipQuery->row();
    foreach ($friendshipQuery->result() as $row) {
```

Your assigning the query as a ->row() element. Take that line out and on the foreach just add this:

```
foreach($friendshipQuery->result() as $row)
```

That should solve it.

Comment: The problem is still persisting. I think it might have to do with the logic.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the generated html? If it doesn't contain that part, it means that `$myuserid == $selectedId` is always true.

Comment: Have you checked the generated html?